# crmsvcutil.exe Identityprovider cannot be null

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

> CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Xrm \Xrm.cs /url:https://mycrm.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /username:name /password:pass /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext

If I run the above command, I get the following error:

> Exiting program with exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   identityProvider

Its a dynamic crm online environment.

Comment: You got a space in `name space:Xrm`, it should be `namespace:Xrm`. this might not be the reason for above error. But its wrong.

Comment: thx, corrected the question. It was correct in the command though.

Comment: I do not know why i was getting error, its said error parameter detail. But when i changed to namaspace:Xmr it works...
Thanks any way, @DemianKasier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this: https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/  If it's missing a feature, let me know.  It'll spit out the correct command line parameters.

Comment: This did it, it's handy it outputs the command it executes. Now to find the diffence between it and my own command...

Comment: @DemianKasier it has loads of features, my favorite is the OptionSetEnum properties that gives you earlybound binding for optionsets.  Just use it and skip doing it all by hand.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem - in my case, there was a trailing space on the end of the username in my CrmSvcUtil.exe.config file.

This:

```
<add key="username" value="me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com" />
```

works fine, but this:

```
<add key="username" value="me@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com " />
```

caused the error:

> Exiting program with exception: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: identityProvider

Comment: jajaja little big help :P

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

don't forget to update the username and password.

`CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://mycrm.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

/out:Xrm.cs /username:<username> /password:<password>

/namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext`

Comment: Just a guess: Try to download the latest SDK and use `CrmSvcUtil` from latest SDK.

Comment: Are you able to ping the server?

Comment: it's an online environment, not on premise. so i don't know what to ping, but I am able to reach the url and log in manually

Comment: I know, you can try to ping Url. Looks like a proxy or firewall issue. But I am glad you have found a workaround. Thanks to Daryl, I also came to know about this tool.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this by changing my username.

We use a single sign-on service. When I log into the CRM in the browser, I am taken to https://login.microsoftonline.com. There, I select my email address. Then the browser is directed to https://sso.mydomain.com. From here, I log in with my email address and regular network password. Then I am connected to the CRM in my browser.

When I change the `/username` parameter to my email address that I use to log into the CRM, instead of my regular username, the problem disappears.